# How to approach mutation with streams in Java

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8, java-stream

```
class Item {
  int id;
  List<PriceDetails> priceDetails;
  String itemName;
}
class PriceDetails {
 String price;
}
```

I am getting multiple items in a JSON file. I am trying to filter priceDetails with empty price (not the items, just removing all the priceDetails in the list with empty price)

***NOTE :*** *I am trying to mutate my item input just because I want all the fields in the items to be same except this `priceDetails`, so I am mutating the item and just trying to add a new `priceDetails` to the same item*

I am able to write Java code, and it's working as expected, but I don't know how to write using Java Streams.

*Code :*

```
public static List<Item> filterByEmptyTicketPrice(List<Item> items) {
    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        List<PriceDetails> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PriceDetails priceDetails : item.priceDetails) {
            if (nonNull(priceDetails.price)) {
                temp.add(priceDetails);
            }
        }
        item.priceDetails = temp;
        result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have this stream-based code, but I want the code with mutation

```
public static List<Item> filterByEmptyTicketPrice(List<Item> items) {
        return items.stream()
                .map(item -> new Item(filterPrices(item.priceDetails)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static List<PriceDetails> filterPrices(List<PriceDetails> priceDetailsList) {
        return priceDetailsList
                .stream()
                .filter(priceDetails -> priceDetails.price != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

public Item(List<PriceDetails> priceDetails) {
    this.priceDetails = priceDetails; }
```

The problem is here:

```
map(item -> new Item(filterPrices(item.priceDetails)))
```

It creates a new `Item` and I am losing all the values of other fields in the item. I don't want to lose all other fields of the item, just wanted to update the item with filtered `priceDetails` (if I find a `null` value).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of utilizing streams, I guess you can get rid of all `priceDetails` containing `null` prices since they hardly could be useful.

You can do it by using Java 8 [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) which is a bulk operation you can perform on any mutable collection. It'll remove all elements that match the given predicate.

```
items.forEach(Item -> item.getpriceDetails()
         .removeIf(priceDetail -> priceDetail.getPrice() == null));
```

***Sidenote:*** don't skip the access modifier while declaring a field. And don't access the attributes directly, use getters instead. If your main background is JavaScript you might be accustomed to that, but in Java it's not a good practice. Class-members must be encapsulated within a class using access modifiers, and in order to make it possible to interact with them, you should provide limited access to them.

Comment: I have 30 more fields in the items, i just gave 3 fields as an example. setting each items fields like this is tough. is there a way without creating new object/item there

Comment: *I have **30** more fields in the items* - **it's a code smell**. I.e. your object wasn't designed properly - I bet you can group some of these properties into separate objects.

Comment: @deepan If you want code to be clean and reliable your streams should be **stateless**. But you might use some Java 8 features to make code concise, I'll show what I mean in a minute.

Comment: @deepan At the very end of the answer, I've added a single statement that will remove null-prices from every item in the source list (without producing a new one).

Comment: Lats one makes sense.But let me try that with my json. will update you soon